# How execute a function inside a dialog?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i want to executing this function this.removeTheme(item) inside of my dialogModal

```
methods: {
deleteTheme(item){
this.$dialog
.confirm('Please confirm to continue')
.then(function(dialog) {
console.log('Clicked on proceed',dialog);
this.removeTheme(item)
})
.catch(function() {
console.log('Clicked on cancel');
});
},
...mapActions([
'removeTheme'
]),
},
```

but dont work what is the problem?

Comment: any error in the browser console?

Comment: @Sphinx nothing, i dont see the errors

Comment: try this `confirm('Please confirm to continue').then((dialog) => {this.removeTheme(item)})`

Comment: @Sphinx worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should meet one context issue because of using `function(){}` for the callback.

So using arrow function will fix the error.

```
this.$dialog
.confirm('Please confirm to continue')
.then((dialog) => { // change function to arrow syntax
console.log('Clicked on proceed',dialog);
this.removeTheme(item)
})
```